# AWS MediaConvert job to create CMAF audio only output

Tags: aws-media-convert, aws-mediaconnect

No matter what I seem to try I can't get AWS MediaConvert to accept a job that is configured to output CMAF or DASH audio only.  I found this on the AWS support forums:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=911037

Which if I understand correctly means that CMAF/DASH audio only output is not supported.  This seems like a glaring omission as in order to build an audio streaming platform compatible with Android and iOS MediaConvert alone is insufficient.

I'm finding so little information (literally none) on producing audio only CMAF that I'm wonder if it's even done?

So the question is; does AWS MediaConvert support CMAF and/or DASH audio only output? assuming no, what are the alternative services/tools that do or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

MediaConvert currently supports the following audio-only output groups and configurations.

[Supported codecs and containers for audio-only outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/supported-codecs-containers-audio-only.html)

Further to the above, I confirmed that there are currently no plans on supporting CMAF audio-only outputs in MediaConvert. This doesn't mean however it will never be supported. The product is constantly improved and if there is enough interest from our customers, it could be added in the future.

[What's New with Media Services?](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/media-services/?whats-new-content.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-content.sort-order=desc&awsf.whats-new-products=general-products%23aws-elemental-mediaconvert)